# How to find all substrings wrapped in "<" and ">"?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regex, which matches the string between "<"and ">".

If the input string is `<c#><ios>`

I would like: `<c#>` and `<ios>`

This seems to be an easy one, but I am new at it.

EDIT : I hoped this should work `new Regex(@"<*>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the implementation of REGEX:

```
'!<([^>]+)>!'
```

or without delimeters

```
'<([^>]+)>'
```

With [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
'!(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)!'
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html for an explanation of lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<*>` regex does not work because it matches strings composed of as many `<` characters as possible - since the `<` is followed by the `*` (greedy 0 or more) quantifier - followed by a single `>` character. For example, the following strings would match:

- `<<<>`
- `<<>`
- `<>`
- `>`

But no string with a non-`<` immediately preceding the `>`, such as `<a>`, would match.

What you need is an expression like `<.*?>` that allows any other character in between the `<` and `>`. See [AbsoluteƵERØ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901411/833844) for some other suggestions.